# Get bean with dynamic constructor arguments

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have a spring component that has an `@Autowired` constructor that takes its arguments from `@Value` annotations. Like this:

```
@Component
public class MyImplClass implement MyInterface
...
public MyImplClass(@Value("${prop.name}") final String name, @Value("${prop.value}") final String value) {
...
}
...
```

in another class i autowire this type like so

```
@Autowired
protected MyInterface _myInterface;
```

now I need to get the MyInterface bean with dynamically generated values (generated in runtime) passed to the constructor. I tried to use an `AbstractBeanFactory` but this didn't work. How do i do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could produce a bean in your Spring config like this:

```
@Bean
public MyInterface getMyInterfaceBean() {
    // Calculate arg values
    String arg1 = ...;
    String arg2 = ...;
    return new MyImplClass(arg1, arg2);
}
```

Even better solution would be to change the constructor of `MyImplClass` to receive a configuration object which will know how to load the required values.